# How do you trigger session garbage collection in PHP < 5.4?

Tags: php, session, php-5.3

I need to force session garbage collection to trigger in PHP, and I'm using version 5.3.3.  I see in PHP 5.4, you can call:

SessionHandler::gc()

What is the best method to get the same result given the PHP version I am using?

Comment: `session_set_save_handler` http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: curious as to why you would need this (it has never come up for me)

Comment: Investigating an issue that happens when a user's session is being garbage collected.  They have an "always stay logged in" flag set, and some necessary values that are stored in the session aren't getting preserved (supposedly...I haven't replicated it yet.) I need to be able to force GC to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For older PHPs, you have to fiddle with the GC probability settings:

```
session.gc_probability 1
session.gc_divisor 1
```

giving a 100% chance of the GC being run on every request. Of course, this would be a major performance hit, so you might want to put those overrides into a conditional block in apache and allow them to be set only for a particular IP or user.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability